# Problem building my diagram with scripts in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, diagram

Diagram making with google script and multiple column

Hello all,

I have a file with names and a few columns I would to integrate into a diagram but I can't seem to be able to.

Here is a sample file :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSRbV.png)

I would like to create a diagram comparing the received calls,picked up calls and lost calls of one person to the total of the team.

Here is a part of the code I have to create the diagram

```
var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("test");
  for (var nbreEmp=2; nbreEmp<lastRow; nbreEmp++){
    if(!ss.getRange("B"+nbreEmp).isBlank()){
      var chart=sheet.newChart();
      chart.addRange(sheet.getRange("A"+nbreEmp+":D"+nbreEmp))
      chart.addRange(sheet.getRange("A"+lastRow+":D"+lastRow))
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
        .setPosition(2,5,0,0)
        .setOption('title',"compare test")
      sheet.insertChart(chart.build());
    }
  }
```

and here is the graph made which is not really what I am expecting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KdEO.png)

Anyone that could enlighten me?

Comment: you should use stacked bar chart. As I can see, I am assuming calls received is just total of calls picked up and Lost calls. stack those two to get received calls number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You can not use `.setChartType()` to get a stacked bar chart.  You have to use `.asBarChart().setStacked()`.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("test");
    let range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn());
    let chart = sheet.newChart()
                .asBarChart().setStacked()
                .addRange(range)
                .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
                .setNumHeaders(1)
                .build();
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Results**

[image]

**Reference**

- [EmbeddedBarChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder#setNumHeaders(Integer))

Comment: @theWizeEd Thanks for the answer. It does help me, but I would like to make a diagram with one person and comparing it to the last name.
So for example : having Name 1 and the last name. Then a new diagram with Name 2 and the last name.
If I do it by adding ranges, the setNumHeaders makes it so that only the first range gets shown on the diagram.
Using your exemple, how to do it by only having NAME1 and NAME 4, then NAME 2 and NAME 4 etc.

Comment: So for your example data you want 3 charts?

Comment: Are you comparing with NAME4 or TOTAL?